# Axios get response detect change

Tags: typescript, axios

I am generating multiple requests through Axios:

```
const statusOrder = (data: any) => {

  const urls: any[] = [];
  const urlsPre =  data.map( (element: any) => element.task_id);
  urlsPre.forEach( (taskId: string) => {
    const newUrlPre = `urlApi...`
    urls.push(newUrlPre)
  });

  const urlsCalls: any[] = [];
  const resultados: any[] = [];

  urls.forEach( (url: any) => {
    return urlsCalls.push(axios.get(url));
  });

  return Promise.allSettled(urlsCalls)
  .then( response => {
    response.map( (element: any) => {
      const item = element.value.data;
      resultados.push(item);
    });
    console.log(resultados);
  })
  .catch( error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

and as a response I receive an array of objects:

```
[
  {
    "success": true,
    "status": processing | ready
  },
  {
    "success": true,
    "status": processing | ready
  },
  {
    "success": true,
    "status": processing | ready
  },
]
```

Always at startup I will receive `status: processing` as a response but after a few seconds (variable time) it changes to `status: ready`. How do I get that new response with `status: ready`?

Comment: For some reason some text in the middle of this question did not get translated to English. It should be "and in response I receive an array of objects"